# while pre-processing i am having huge count of columns with nan values! any possible way to replace with all columns nan with "Zero" or 'N'

Tags: pandas, preprocessor

For example, i am converted all the columns as list  `sample['ib_home_market_value','ib_comm_involve_don_cultural','ib_comm_involve_political','ib_home_furnishings', 'ib_magazines','ib_womens_apparel']`

similar i am having 200 + columns.
Total rows - 10L

`Sample [ib_comm_involve_don_cultural]- Y -309639  NAN -690361`

similar i am need to work for all columns to change either 'Zero' and 'N'. I am required function to change all the columns nan values.

Am doing preprocessing for clustering model :

Comment: I guess you are looking for `DataFrame.fillna()`. But please supply sample data and reformat your question so the code is more readable. It's hard to even guess what you mean

Comment: you can fill na values of a column using `df[['ib_comm_involve_don_cultural']] = df[['ib_comm_involve_don_cultural']].fillna('N')`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the code un-readable, i am tried and fillna applied.

for i in list1:
    df1[i].fillna('N', inplace=True)